# My Mediaplayer got stuck after once

Tags: java, android, audio

There are two buttons in my UI. These two buttons have two audio separately, I have mentioned it as `dk1` and `dk2`.

What I want:

1. To stop `dk1` when `dk2` is pressed
2. To repeat the procedure all time
3. I want to create another 6 audio like above `dk1` and `dk2`

The problem: I can't paly like this more than one time. This is my code:

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //Media Player Loops

    //Loops
    MediaPlayer dk1;
    MediaPlayer dk2;   

    //Mediaplayer Location
    dk1 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.dholak01);
    dk2 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.dholak03);
}

  //Looping and start Media Player

  public void playdk1 (View view) {
     if (dk1.isPlaying() == true) {
        dk1.stop();
        return;
    }

    if (dk2.isPlaying() == true) {
        dk2.stop();
    } else {
         dk1.start();
         dk1.setLooping(true);
    }
 }

 public void playdk2 (View view) {
    if (dk2.isPlaying() == true) {
        dk2.stop();
        return;
    }

    if (dk1.isPlaying() == true) {
        dk1.stop();
    } else {
          dk2.start();
          dk2.setLooping(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void playdk1 (View view) 
if (dk1.isPlaying() == true) {
     dk1.stop();   
   }
 else{
    dk2.start();
    dk2.setLooping(true);}

if (dk2.isPlaying() == true) {
  dk2.stop();
} else {
dk1.start();
dk1.setLooping(true);
}
}

 public void playdk2 (View view) {
 if (dk2.isPlaying() == true) {
     dk2.stop();

     }
      else {
          dk1.start();
          dk1.setLooping(true);
        }

     if (dk1.isPlaying() == true) {
       dk1.stop();
       } else {
          dk2.start();
          dk2.setLooping(true);
        }
         }
```